# Why does my attempted rvest web scrape yield too much or too little data?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape a single table from the following URL: https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/league?season=2023#statcastHitting. However, my attempts either scrape multiple tables on the broader page or else I get an output tibble of 0x0. I simply want to scrape the "Statcast Hitting" table near the top of the page, sans spanner titles. I used Selector Gadget to try and pinpoint the correct nodes however I suspect I am not referencing the html properly. An image of what I'm trying to scrape and convert to a dataframe is shown below.

[image]

I have tried several times, with a couple of failed attempts below.

1. First attempt successfully pulls the entire page but this obviously overshoots the mark:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
url <- 'https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/league?season=2023#statcastHitting'

savant_teams <- url %>% read_html %>% html_node('#statcastHitting') %>%
html_table() 

savant_teams
```

2. Second attempt (once again using html pasted from Selector Gadget) yields a 0x0 tibble (and the html_node language is way longer than I was expecting):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/league?season=2023#statcastHitting'
savant_teams <- url %>% read_html %>% html_node('#statcast_th-8 .tablesorter-header-inner , #statcast_th-7 , #statcast_th-6 .tablesorter-header-inner , #statcast_th-5 .tablesorter-header-inner , #statcast_th-10 .tablesorter-header-inner , #statcast_th-4 .tablesorter-header-inner , #statcast_th-2 .tablesorter-header-inner , #statcast_th-9 , #statcast_th-1 .tablesorter-header-inner , #statcast_th-3 .tablesorter-header-inner , .tablesorterb23e763259572 #statcast_th-0 .tablesorter-header-inner , #scg_ span') %>%
  html_table() 
savant_teams
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tables are wrapped in a `div` with class `table-savant`. And as the table you want to scrape is the first you could use the selector `#statcastHitting div.table-savant` to select the first `div` to get only the table inside that `div`:

```r
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
url <- 'https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/league?season=2023#statcastHitting'

savant_teams <- url %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_node('#statcastHitting div.table-savant') %>%
  html_table()

savant_teams
#> # A tibble: 32 × 27
#>    ``     ``     `Standard Stats` `Standard Stats` `Standard Stats`
#>    <chr>  <chr>  <chr>            <chr>            <chr>           
#>  1 "Team" Season PA               AB               H               
#>  2 ""     2023   6,249            5,597            1,543           
#>  3 ""     2023   5,985            5,428            1,325           
#>  4 ""     2023   6,207            5,541            1,417           
#>  5 ""     2023   5,980            5,501            1,308           
#>  6 ""     2023   6,253            5,567            1,441           
#>  7 ""     2023   6,219            5,489            1,336           
#>  8 ""     2023   5,966            5,311            1,187           
#>  9 ""     2023   6,164            5,511            1,432           
#> 10 ""     2023   6,180            5,401            1,316           
#> # ℹ 22 more rows
#> # ℹ 22 more variables: `Standard Stats` <chr>, `Standard Stats` <chr>,
#> #   `Standard Stats` <chr>, `Standard Stats` <chr>, `Standard Stats` <chr>,
#> #   `Standard Stats` <chr>, `Standard Stats` <chr>, `Standard Stats` <chr>,
#> #   `Standard Stats` <chr>, `Standard Stats` <chr>, Statcast <chr>,
#> #   Statcast <chr>, Statcast <chr>, Statcast <chr>, Statcast <chr>,
#> #   Statcast <chr>, Statcast <chr>, Statcast <chr>, Statcast <chr>, …
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is the best way to obtain the div information via right click + Inspect in the Chrome browser? Also, it would seem that to scrape the second table I could simply use ```savant_plate_discipline <- url %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_node('#statcast_plate_discipline div.table-savant') %>%
  html_table()``` however that throws an error. What would be the proper html_code in that case?

Comment: Yes. Would not call it the "best" way. But if you want to scrape a webpage it's the first step to have a look at the HTMl structure of that page. And no: you can't use `#statcast_plate_discipline` as this will pick the div with that id. And that div does not contain the table you are looking for. But you can use `html_element("#statcastHitting #playeDiscipline")` or what I would prefer use xpath  to pick the second table: `html_element(xpath = "//div[@id='statcastHitting']/div[@class='table-savant'][2]")`

Comment: Very helpful, both solutions work. Much appreciated.